# Python Web Scraper not populating .txt file with any scraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm new to python but I have a slight grasp on what's going on. I'm trying to write a web scraper with BeautifulSoup. I'm tyring to scrape a site for a string of numbers and then to write that string of numbers into a .txt file so that I can later come back and use that .txt file as a dataset.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Scrape the links to each monthly results page
url = "http://www.calotteryx.com/Fantasy-5/drawing-results-calendar.htm"
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
links = []
for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="td0"):
    href = link.get("href")
    if href:
        links.append(href)

# Scrape the winning numbers for each monthly results page
winning_numbers = []
for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    content = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup.find_all("div", class_="ball blue5 fcblack1"):
        numbers = tag.text.strip().split()
        winning_numbers.append(numbers)

# Write the winning numbers to a file
with open("winning_numbers.txt", "w") as f:
    for numbers in winning_numbers:
        f.write(" ".join(numbers) + "\n")
```

This is my code, and when I run it I don't get any errors, but I also end up with a blank "winning_numbers.txt" file. Could someone help to point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 1):

`<td>` elements do not have the `href` attribute; you want the `href` of the `<a>` element inside.

In addition, the links are all relative, so you will need to join it to the base URL to make further requests (which can be done with `urllib.parse.urljoin`).

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

for link in soup.find_all("td", class_="td0"):
    anchor = link.find('a')
    if anchor and (href := anchor.get('href')):
        links.append(urljoin(url, href))
```